# Check if bot has permissions in a specific channel discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to figure out how to check if my bot has the right ViewChannel and SendMessages in a certain channel. I tried discord.js v13 variant with `if(!interaction.guild.me.permissionsIn(channel).has("VIEW_CHANNEL))`. Then upgraded it to discord.js v14. `if(!interaction. guild.members.me.permissionsIn(channel).has([PermissionsFlagsBits.ViewChannel, PermissionsFlagsBits.SendMessages]))`

But there I keep getting the same error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') at GuildMemberRoleManager.get cache [as cache] (C:\Users\sdamz\OneDrive\Desktop\dcbot v2\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberRoleManager.js:37:101) ...`

Already did it with just

`if(!interaction.guild.members.me.permissions.has([PermissionsFlagsBits.ViewChannel, PermissionsFlagsBits.SendMessagesl])`

but got the same error.

I would appreciate an answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need the `Guilds` intent

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, /* other intents */]
})
```

The problem is [here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/main/packages/discord.js/src/managers/GuildMemberRoleManager.js#L37). It tries to set the everyone role, but it's uncached, without `Guilds` intent.

Also, there is a typo: `PermissionsFlagsBits` should be `PermissionFlagsBits`.

Answer (score -1):

I was also struggling with this problem and this is what worked for me:

```
(interaction.guild.members.me).permissionsIn("Your_Channel_ID").has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages);
```

Comment: How is this different? How does this solve the original issue? The error states that `everyone` is `undefined`. It's probably because OP hasn't enabled the required intents (mentioned in the other answer).

Comment: I was getting the same error as OP even with the required intents and when I checked each permission individually I did not get that error.

Comment: So, I've just tested it on one of my test bots. OP's code only throws an error if the `Guilds` intent is not enabled. It's perfectly valid to provide an array of `PermissionResolvable`s in [`permissionsIn(channelId).has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PermissionResolvable)